# Wrong use of pointers to index elements

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to iterate through an array of length 3 and input then output all of the items, which are integers. I have two codes, the first of which works without any issues while the second one fails. Kindly tell what is the problem:

CODE 1:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

int arr[3];
for(int& element : arr) {cin >> element; cout << element << endl;}

return 0;
}
```

CODE 2:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

int arr[3];
cin >> &arr[0] >> &arr[1] >> &arr[2];
cout << arr[0] << arr[1] << arr[2];
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify what's wrong with the second program? How is it failing?

Comment: The second program fails *how*?

Comment: cin >> &arr[0] >> &arr[1] >> &arr[2] remove the "&" and try again...

Comment: As a possible guess, I think you're confusing input using C++ streams, with input using the old C function `scanf`. Please take a step back and read your text-book or tutorial again about input using `cin`.

Comment: The error is coming on line 8. It is something like error: no match for 'operator>>' (operand types are 'std::istream...)

Comment: Quote it in full. "something like" is no use to readers. But it seems you're just confused about the `&` symbol and its different meanings. Pass `cin` a _reference_, not a pointer. Passing `&arr[0]` and so on means 'address of `arr[0]`' and so on. That's wrong here. The `&` in the first variant means 'loop over references to the elements'. So the cause is basically just a typo. Instead just pass `arr[0]` and so on, no `&` needed.

Comment: @SvenNilsson Why do you need to have & in the first method and not in the second one? (I know this is a very stupid question for someone who knows his coding but please consider explaining)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you spot the difference?

```
// works
cin  >> element
cout << element

// doesn't work
cin  >> &arr[0]
cout <<  arr[0]
```

The unary operator `&` is the addressof operator. When you apply the addressof operator on the element of the array, you get a pointer to the element.

When you pass that pointer to the stream extraction operator o `std::cin`, you get an error because the standard library doesn't define an extraction operator for pointers. Another problem is that the result of the operation is a prvalue, and the non-const lvalue reference parameter of the extraction operator cannot be bound to a prvalue.

Given that your intention seems to be to extract input into the element as in the first program, the fix to the bug is to pass the element itself to the operator rather than the pointer - just like you do in the first example, and just like you do in the output of the second example:

```
cin >> arr[0]
```

> Why do you need to have & in the first method and not in the second one?

You don't have operator & in the first example. You could add it to make the first example equally broken:

```
cin >> &element
//     ^ Added this to break the example
```